# ¿Por qué en español se debe cambiar la -i final por -y?

Tags: historia, ortografía, vocales

Anoche, leyendo un libro, me encontré con la palabra *poni*. Al principio se me hizo raro que no acabara en *-y*, así que me fui a buscar la norma de la ortografía española al respecto, y vi que solo se escriben con *y* final las palabras que acaban en *i* precedida de vocal. Como no era el caso, la di por buena.

Nótese que dice simplemente "precedida de vocal", sin especificar si es tónica o átona. Así pues, la RAE recomienda escribir *[samuray](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=samur%C3%A1i)* y *[paipay](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=paip%C3%A1i)* en vez de *samurái* y *paipái* (por adaptarse mejor a las normas), aunque reconoce que estas últimas formas son las más utilizadas.

Una vez pasado este trámite, me di cuenta de que en los idiomas vecinos esta norma no se sigue. Por ejemplo, si en español tenemos *rey*, en catalán, gallego y portugués tenemos *rei*, y en francés tenemos *roi*.

Así pues, ¿cuál es el motivo histórico de que el español concretamente tenga esta norma? ¿Qué origen tiene?

Comment: According to French Wikipedia it used to be _roy_ https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy in French. Not sure if that helps, perhaps the terminal -y came first?

Comment: El plural de *rey* es *reyes* en castellano, pero en GL/PT/AST el plural de rei es simplemente *reis* (imagino también en CA, pero no lo hablo). Yo siempre pensaba que era por eso

Comment: @guifa efectivamente, en catalán el plural de _rei_ es _reis_.

Comment: Estoy anodadado porque creía que la RAE recomendaba **paipái** y así el plural era **paipáis**. Si ahora se escribe **paipay** ¿el plural es **paipayes** como buey/bueyes, rey/reyes, ley/leyes,...?

Comment: @Jdamian en realidad no. La forma asentada es _paipái_ y su plural es _paipáis_. Otra cosa es que a la RAE le habría gustado que se siguiera la norma general, pero reconoce que la forma asentada es la que acaba en _-i_. Curioso es si miras el DLE: _paipái_ redirige a _paipay_, pero _samuray_ redirige a _samurái_, y de _bonsái_ ni siquiera se recoge la versión acabada en _-y_.

Comment: aunque fuera *paipay* el plural sería igualmente *paipáis*, igual que el plural de *gay* es *gais* y no *gayes*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *rey, ley, grey, buey*

I believe this is due to the plural forms of *buey(es), grey(es), ley(es), rey(es)*.

These are the only Latin-descended words in Spanish which end *-y*. With the exception of *buey* (which evolved by semantic analogy to *grey*), their Latin precursors all ended in *-egem* etc, which evolved /egem/ > /ege/ > /eje/ > /ej/. Thus they are the earliest (and only 'naturally inherited') Spanish words ending in a stressed /ej/.

Over the centuries there was free variation as to whether to spell the singular forms with a terminal *-i* or -*y*. Indeed *rei, lei* etc appear as alternate orthographies in several dictionaries from the 15th - 19th centuries (NTLLE):

> Tambien la usan en Cast. en algunas ocasiones como en *ley, Rey,* aunque sea mera vocal, y si bien aqui no habia equivocacion, y se podia conservar, seguimos á muchos que la quitan, y escriben *Lei, Rei*, &c.
>
> - *1788 TERREROS Y PANDO (P-Z)*

**Given their plural forms end in /ejes/, and intervocalic /j/ is usually<sup>1 2</sup> written *-y-*, it seems natural to assume the *-y* singular forms won out by analogy to the relatively stable plural spelling.**

Note that in Old French, Old Portuguese, and Old Occitan we *do* see orthographies in *-y*. However, in most modern romance languages (Spanish being a notable exception), the plural of these words are *-eis* or *-es*, thus lacking the /VjV/ impetus for a distinct orthography.

---

## Later *-y* words

Once the orthographies of the above Latin-origin words had been established, it's natural that any new Spanish words ending in a stressed /Vj/ would suit the same orthography.

Such words fall into a handful of different groups:

#### Derivatives

- detienebuey, matabuey, vacabuey, güey, virrey/visorrey

#### Contractions

- [estoy, doy, soy, voy](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/33052/sobre-el-cl%c3%adtico-locativo-medieval-y/33053#33053)
- ahí, valahí/velay, hay (< ha i < ha ahí)
- hoy, doy (< de hoy), acroy, choroy, coicoy

#### Apocopation

- fray/frey (freile < fraile), muy (< muito > mucho), taray (taraje < tarahe)
- cucuy/cocuy (cocuyo), pijibay (pejibaye)

#### Onomatopoeia

- ay, ayayay, ajajay/jajay, alalay, caray, huy, uy, picuy/pijuy, pitoitoy, guay, guirigay

#### Foreign loanwords

- `quechua` [cacuy](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyctibius_griseus#Nombres_comunes)), chuchuy, arrarray, atatay/tatay, pacay, huacatay, chachay, ananay, amancay, achalay
- `mapuche` cuicuy, quilmay, quillay, colliguay
- `guaraní` timboy/timbó, urunday/urundey, urunday, ñandubay, curupay, aguaribay; `tupí` margay; `paipay` paipái/paipay
- `taíno` caney, carey/caray, copey, mamey, maguey; `caribean` batey, quibey
- `Cuban flora & fauna` catey, ..., curamagüey, curujey, guararey, jagüey, yarey
- `tagalo` sangley, sinamay, barangay, anay;
- `turkish` dey
- `greek` escay
- `french` bocoy, convoy, lay, estay, contraestay, ensay; `portuguese` balay
- `english` boy, corderoy, yérsey, yóquey, vóley, póney, monterrey, tubey, órsay, gray, gay, espray, cambray; `dutch` coy

Though there are a handful exceptions in *-i*, almost all of them have alternative orthographies with *-y*:

- `latin` agnusdéi
- `french` espahí/espay, chií, cai, rai
- `japanese` bonsái, samuray/samurái, haikai/hai-kai
- `english` masái
- `quechua` cocuy/cocui, cuy/cui
- `guaraní` cay/caí, tipoy/tipói/tipoi, yatay/achachay/yataí, bacaray/vacaray/vacaraí
- `pascuense` moái
- `caló` chai, jai

### Others

- fai

---

**Notes:**

<sup>1. Exceptions are exclusively learned greek loans e.g. *elaiotecnia, meiosis, pereion, paranoia* or demonyms *hawaiano, amambaiense, ushuaiense*.</sup>

> <sup>2. **Y.** ... nos sirve de letra consonante, quando he de herir á la vocal siguiente: como en Yermo o Mayo.</sup>
> <sup>- RAE 1739</sup>

Answer (score -1):

No pienso que exista una razón histórica, me parece que la RAE crea normas como esta con el propósito de tener una ortografía "regular" para el español. De lo contrario, tendríamos algunas palabras con la combinación "ai" y algunas otras con "ay", sin regla alguna que nos ayude a saber la ortografía correcta en cada caso. Unificando esta combinación de fonemas bajo una misma forma evitaría cometer errores ortográficos.

Comment: Interesante opinión pero esto no responde la pregunta.

Comment: @walen cuando Mariano dice " me parece que la RAE crea normas...." eso es una opinión (muy interesante por supuesto) pero recuerda que la RAE no crea normas porque si. Su misión esta escrita así **«es una institución ... que tiene como misión principal velar por que los cambios que experimente la lengua española en su constante adaptación a las necesidades de sus hablantes no quiebren la esencial unidad que mantiene en todo el ámbito hispánico». La RAE recoge los usos. No crea normas porque si. Lo dicen todo el tiempo en twitter. Entonces los usos no se dan porque la RAE dice sino al contrario

Comment: @walen ...y esa es tu opinión. También se usa "Not an answer" cuando se piensa que la respuesta corresponde más a un comentario. Ese es este caso. Para mi esto no es una respuesta. Para ti si lo es. Eso es absolutamente claro. Como caso curioso de cientos de flags que he usado en este sitio es la primera vez que alguien siquiera comenta al respecto.