# Sobre el clítico locativo medieval "y"

Tags: etimología, historia, clíticos, español-medieval

En las [*Actas del XXIII Congreso internacional de lingüística y filología románica*](https://books.google.es/books?id=Wg-yDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=cl%C3%ADtico+locativo+espa%C3%B1ol+y+medieval&source=bl&ots=AdYnOcVrML&sig=ACfU3U2u-nur03sWaG1-j3616EyFwFqrtg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjzwOHy59_nAhUZA2MBHamRBUQQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=cl%C3%ADtico%20locativo%20espa%C3%B1ol%20y%20medieval&f=false) se menciona que en el español medieval existía un clítico locativo "y" análogo al francés "y", al catalán "hi" y al italiano "ci". También se explica que, en el castellano actual, este clítico se encuentra incorporado en la primera persona del singular del presente de indicativo del verbo "ir": correspondería a la "y" final de "voy":

> Además, el clítico locativo medieval del español y, que marca el Término, se halla incorporado en la raíz verbal de la primera persona del singular del presente de indicativo de la forma *vo* (*voy*).

¿Significa esto que en español medieval se usó la forma "y vo"? ¿Podemos encontrar  ejemplos de uso de este clítico "y"? ¿Existen otras trazas de este clítico medieval en el castellano de hoy en día? ¿Cuándo dejó de usarse?

Comment: Sin tener una fuente ahora mismo, tengo casi 100% de seguridad de que "hay" también proviene de este clítico (compara con el francés "il y a"). Con algo menos de seguridad, "soy" y "estoy" también podrían estar relacionados con él.

Comment: @wimi: Parece que tienes razón sobre ["hay"](http://forums.tomisimo.org/showthread.php?t=11517).

Answer (score 7):

*Hay* viene [inequívocamente](https://www.nebrija.com/revista-linguistica/fundamento-teorico-de-un-modelo-para-trabajar-los-verbos-haber-estar-y-ser-en-el-aula-de-ele.html) de la contracción *hay < ha hi < ha ahí* (cf. cat. *hi ha*, fr. *il y a*).

No obstante la hipótesis de que *soy, doy, voy, estoy* (de *so, do, vo, esto*) también vengan de tal contracción es solo una de las múltiples explicaciones propuestas sobre sus etimologías. [Español *soy, estoy, doy, voy*: un intento de explicación morfológica](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BnbQDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=voy+soy+estoy+doy+y) recoge las más prominentes:

> #### 1.2 TEORÍAS
>
> Las diferentes propuestas sobre el origen de -y en soy, estoy, doy y
>   voy pueden sintetizarse en siete grupos <sup>12</sup>.
>
> #### (i) Paragoge
>
> Sostenida por Lausberg<sup>13</sup> y Pensado <sup>14</sup>. Según esta tesis, *-y* procedería de una *-e* paragógica. La base [SU < SUM] con vocal paragógica sonaba SUE o SUU y de donde proceden las formas del provenzal antiguo, español y portugués. El apoyo fundamental de esta teoría es el leonés antiguo *soe* y las formas idénticas *doe, soe* del sardo logudorés y el veneciano antiguo *soe, dae, estoe*. Pensado interpreta el valor de la grafía *soe*: «[…] como cabe esperar de su función conectiva, la *-e* perdería su silabicidad: [sóe̯]. Tal diptongo sería perfectamente posible. Sin embargo, una evolución muy natural es su cerrazón en la semivocal óptima: [sói◌̯]. El proceso consiste en la cerrazón de una semivocal, no de una vocal» <sup>15</sup>.
>
> #### (ii) HABEO
>
> La influencia de la primera persona de indicativo *ey < *ay(o) < HABEO*, fue defendida por Meyer Lúbke (1885), Hanssen (1896; 1945) y Zauner (1905).
>
> #### (iii) FU.Ī
>
> La *-y* de *soy, estoy, doy* y *voy* es debida a la influencia analógica de la primera persona del pretérito /fui/ < FU.Ī. Esta teoría, adoptada por Wanner <sup>16</sup>, sigue la que propuso Pope para el francés medieval *suis*. La distancia analógica entre el español /so/ y /fuj/ representa una distancia de dos características mínimas: fonéticamente de /'u/ a /'o/ (en francés de /'y/ a /'u/ ) y morfológicamente de pretérito a presente de indicativo (como en francés). El estatus de terminación de /j/ en el pretérito castellano resalta claramente de la constitución del paradigma de pretérito de este verbo. La primera persona singular presenta /'fuj/ (más tarde /'f'wi/ ) y menos frecuente /'fu/, y /'fue/ , menos frecuente /'fu/ la tercera singular. Esta constelación produce un análisis sincrónico castellano medieval de /fu + í/, /fu + ∅/ 3s pret. contra /fu + e/, /fu + ∅/ <sup>33</sup> pret., de la que la terminación marcada /j/ para la primera persona singular puede ser fácilmente abastraída y extendida a otra primera persona del mismo verbo de constitución paralela. Los restantes verbos *do, vo, estó* se convierten en *doy, voy, estoy* por analogía con *soy*.
>
> #### (iv) Alternancia /oj/ ~ /ow/
>
> En el área leonesa, gallega y portuguesa existe una variación de diptongos desde el s. XIV entre /OW/ y /oj/ en los resultados de los grupos latinos /pt/ y / kt/ , con algunas extensiones de contexto tardías como /'kowza/ ~ /'kojza/ < CAUSA. El etimológico *vou* < UADO afectó a *so > sou* y *estó > estou*, *do > dou* (de SUM, DO, STO). Una forma alternante *voj*, debida a la variación de diptongos /ow/ ~ /oj/, pudo haber generado *sou/soj, dou/doj y estou/estoj* en territorio leonés. Las formas /ow/ pertenecen al occidente leonés y al gallego y portugués, /oj/ al leonés oriental. Esta teoría ha sido sostenida por de Gorog: las formas verbales en *-oy* se habrían originado en una parte de León donde se tenía consciencia del hecho de que *oi* en algunas hablas correspondía el *au* en otras <sup>17</sup>.
>
> #### (v) Adverbio locativo *y* "allí"
>
> Una de las teorías más aceptadas hasta poder ser considerada una opinión común <sup>18</sup>. La fuente de *-y* estaría en la aglutinación del frecuente adverbio locativo medieval *(h)y, (h)i* "allí" a los cuatro verbos *so, do, vo, estó,* empleado como sustituto del pronombre de dativo, partiendo de la idea de “doy a aquel lugar”, por ejemplo, «a aquel monasterio»; en los casos de *voy, soy* y *estoy* el significado del verbo correspondiente se presta también a la aglutinación de un adverbio de lugar (v.g. *so y pagado/a*), lo mismo que a una propagación desde *doy* <sup>19</sup>.
>
> #### (vi) Pronombre sujeto *yo*
>
> Esta hipótesis fue enunciada por J.D.M. Ford en 1911 y ha sido retomada más recientemente por Schmide<sup>20</sup> y Gago-Jover<sup>21</sup>: *doy, estoy, soy, voy* se deberían a un refuerzo de las formas verbales monosilábicas *do, sto, so, vo* por posposición del pronombre correspondiente y la posterior reintepretación de la estructura sílábica: [só—yó] > [sói◌̯—yó]; la secuencia *do yo* (o *so yo* …) habría dado *doy yo* (o *soy yo* …) y, con omisión del pronombre en casos de menor énfasis o con voluntad de eliminar una redundancia, *doy* (o *soy* …). De esta forma, según Schmidely, «la yod desinencíal no sería sino la huella del pronombre de primera persona *yo* en una voluntad de reforzar ciertas formas verbales de mismo rango personal que tenían como características un significante monosilábico, terminado por *-o*, y una alta frecuencia de empleo» <sup>22</sup>.
>
> #### (vii) Existencial *hay*
>
> La influencia del existencial *hay* en el origen se *soy, estoy, doy* y *voy* ha sido propuesta por Molho <sup>23</sup>. Molho lleva a cabo la construcción de una semiología apropiada de los verbos de existencia. Esta construcción se basa en el tratamiento particular de un pronombre—adverbio anafórico, cuya representación, lentamente reelaborada, se ha profundizado hasta el grado de no presentarse ya como una palabra reconocible susceptible de aparecer independientemente en la frase, sino como un morfema sufijado protector de una vocal desinencial. Los fenómenos evocados por Molho se han originado por un accidente psico-fónico: la colusión en la frase del verbo unipersonal HABER en presente de indicativo y del pronombre anafórico que se aglutina por enclisis *(h)a + y*. Una vez constituido el presente *(h)ay* en el s. XIII, el elemento *-y* comienza a propagarse por analogía al presente de otro verbo que connota en el pensamiento castellano la noción fundamental de existencia: *soy* aparece entonces al lado de *so*. Por oposición a *haber*, que aporta la representación de la existencia por interioridad, *ser* significa desde los orígenes de la lengua la existencia por exterioridad. Solamente
>   después de haberse sufijado a *so* (→ *so-y*), el elemento *-y*, en calidad de sufijo desinencial, se extiende a otros tres verbos situados por detrás en la jerarquía semasiológica de las nociones verbales y que mantienen con la noción de “ser” relaciones ideales estrechas: *vo-y ~ esto-y ~ do-y*.
>
> <sup>12 En el trabajo de Wanner, [«An analogical solution for Spanish *soy, doy,
>   voy* and *estoy*»](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/prbs.2006.18.issue-2/probus.2006.009/probus.2006.009.xml), pp. 274-278 y 291-294, se puede encontrar un buen resumen y crítica de las teorías propuestas.</sup>
>   <sup>13 Lausberg, [*Lingüística románica*, II](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=y1ZfAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=882), § 882.</sup>
>   <sup>14 Pensado, [«*Soy, estoy, doy, voy* como solución de una dificultad fonotáctica»](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Soy%2C-estoy%2C-doy%2C-voy-como-soluci%C3%B3n-de-una-Ruiz/ea180a4b5e96c743ba4b2b4ddf9ac819a582cb71).</sup>
>   <sup>15 *Ivi*, p.215.</sup>
>   <sup>16 Wanner, [«An analogical solution for Spanish *soy, doy, voy and estoy*»](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/prbs.2006.18.issue-2/probus.2006.009/probus.2006.009.xml).</sup>
>   <sup>17 de Gorog, [«L'origine des formes espagnoles *doy, estoy, soy, voy*»](https://www.persee.fr/doc/cehm_0396-9045_1980_num_5_1_998).</sup>
>   <sup>18 Primer estudio monográfico de Müller, [«Spanisch *soy, estoy, doy, voy* im Lichte der romanischen Endungsneubildung mit Flexionsfremden Elementen»](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27937038).</sup>
>   <sup>19 *DCECH* II 425b14-26.</sup>
>   <sup>20 [«La *-y* de *doy, estoy, soy, voy*»](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/articulo?codigo=556479).</sup>
>   <sup>21 [«Nuevos datos sobre el origen de *soy, doy, voy, estoy*»](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/articulo?codigo=1110288).</sup>
>   <sup>22 Schmidely, [«La *-y* de *doy, estoy, soy, voy*»](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/articulo?codigo=556479), p. 615.</sup>
>   <sup>23 [«*Soy (voy~estoy~doy)*. Essai sur la sémiologie des verbes d'existence en espagnol»](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Essai_sur_la_s%C3%A9miologie_des_verbes_d_ex.html?id=LmgUtAEACAAJ).</sup>

Comment: sobre (iv): siguen vivas las formas (-o, -ou, -oi) en los distintos dialectos de los idiomas procedientes del leonés antiguo (asturiano, eonaviego, mirandés, leonés moderno) en el portugués (donde escriben normalmente -ou pero según zona dicen /o/ u /ou/, pero en algunas palabras/zonas, dicen y escriben /oi/)

Answer (score 2):

Para completar la respuesta de @ukemi, en el artículo ["Los complementos locativos"](http://weba575.webs.uvigo.es/jmgm/public/locativos.pdf), de José Mª García-Miguel
(Universidade de Vigo), entre otras cosas se hace un estudio sobre la presencia de diferentes adverbios locativos en un corpus formado por una serie de fragmentos, que, en palabras del autor,  "pretenden servir de muestra del español medieval y clásico". Se trata de fragmentos del *Poema de Mío Cid*, del *Libro del Cavallero Zifar*, de *La Celestina*, de la *Segunda parte del ingenioso caballero don 
Quijote de La Mancha* y de los *Documentos lingüísticos de la Nueva España. Altiplano Central (1525-1816)* recopilados por Concepción Company, de los cuales se han seleccionado una serie de textos que comprenden el período 1600-1650.

La conclusión referente al clítico locativo "y" a la cual se llega es la siguiente:

> En cuanto a *y*, es el adverbio locativo más frecuente en español medieval, hasta que desaparece, siendo sustituido en muchos de sus usos por *allí*.

Y también:

> Muchas veces encontramos oraciones con *y*, que difícilmente 
>   podrían verterse en español actual con un adverbio equivalente, o que simplemente las diríamos ahora suprimiendo el adverbio [...].

En el artículo se explica que esta desaparición tuvo lugar en el siglo XV. De hecho, en los fragmentos de *La Celestina* (1499) que han sido objeto de estudio aperece una sola vez y, además, este "y" de *La Celestina* no aparece en todas sus ediciones. Pero en los textos anteriores se encuentra muchas veces.

A continuación, damos algunos ejemplos de frases donde aparece el clítico locativo "y" citadas en el artículo mencionado. Se usan "Cid" y "Zifar" para indicar respectivamente el *Poema de Mío Cid* y el *Libro del Cavallero Zifar*. Nótese que en uno de estos ejemplos, aparece "y ha" (que es lo que ha dado lugar a la forma verbal "hay"):

> - E asi es establesçido e otorgado de los padres santos que ningunt cuerpo 
>     que fuese y enterrado que non sea ende sacado (Zifar, prólogo, 3).
> - E sy non fueran y llegados perdierase la villa (Zifar, 20, 50).
> - Que enel castiello non y aurie morada (Cid, 525).
> - Cuydaron algunos que non fueran verdaderas las cosas que se y contienen 
>     (Zifar, 1, 9).
> - Bien gelo demostraron atodos .vj. commo son,
>     
>     Que por y serie vençido qui saliesse del moion (Cid, 3606-7).
> - E otro dia en la mañaña fue el Cauallero Zifar a la ribera de la mar, e 
>     andando por y vio vna naue (Zifar, 41, 87).
> - Que enel castiello non y aurie morada (Cid, 525).
> - En San Pero de Cardena y nos cante el gallo (Cid, 209).
> - Alterçer dia, don yxo y es tornado (Cid, 938).
> - Aguijo myo Çid, yuas caba delant, y ffinco en vn poyo que es sobre Mont Real (Cid, 863).
> - E como venia cansado e lazrado de fanbre, metiose en vna hermita que fallo 
>     y çerca de la çibdat, syn puertas (Zifar, 6, 028).
> - Entre Minaya & los buenos que y ha (Cid, 3058).
> - Con quantos que ellos traen y iazen essa noch (Cid, 2702).
> - Daqui quito castiella, pues que el Rey he en yra;
>     
>     Non se sientrare y mas entodos los myos dias (Cid, 219-220).
> - commo le contesçio en Florençia vna vegada, que gelo quisieron tomar por 
>     lo enterrar y (Zifar, prólogo, 4).
> - E despues que llego a Logroño descubriolo, e fue y resçebido mucho 
>     onrradamente de don Ferrando (Zifar, prólogo, 4).
> - dixole de commo el su medio amigo le resçebiera muy bien, e que luego 
>     quel conto el fecho, e le respondiera que aquello e mas faria por el, e que 
>     feziera una fuesa so el lecho e que lo soterraran y (Zifar 5, 20).
> - El obispo don Iheronimo adelant se en traua, 
>     
>     Y dexaua el cauallo, pora la capiella adelinaua (Cid, 1579-1580).
> - E despues que llego a Logroño descubriolo, e fue y resçebido mucho onrradamente de don Ferrando, obispo de Calahorra (Zifar, prólogo, 4).
> - La dueña andido por la naue catando todas las cosas que en ella eran, e fallo 
>     y cosas muy nobles e de grant preçio (Zifar, 45, 97).